# How to generate unique request id for each log4j request

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am printing log of request and response by using log4j. I want to assign a unique ID to each request and same ID to its response, there are multiple requests so it will be easier for me to identify each request and response.

This is what i was using, but its not working. Its updating the UDID on response as well.

```
    public void logRequestObject(HttpServletRequest httprequest){
    uniqueID= UUID.randomUUID().toString();          
    logger.info("Log4J - "+ "Request: requestId= "+ uniqueID+  ",Headers= "+ map);  
}

    public void logResponseObject(HttpServletResponse httpResponse){    
      logger.info("Log4J - "+ "Response: ,requestId= " + uniqueID + " ,responseTime= " + " totalTime= "+ totalTime);        
}
```

Then i came to know that log4j provides a way to record unique ID to each request.

I have read many posts on stackoverflow, but still unable to understand it.

This is my `properties` files.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file, CATALINA

# Catalina

    log4j.appender.CATALINA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.File=${catalina.home}/logs/catalina.out
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.MaxFileSize=10MB
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.MaxBackupIndex=5
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}  %X{RequestId} %p-%c{1}: [%m]%n
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.Append=true
    log4j.appender.CATALINA.Encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Is the class which holds the `uniqueID` thread safe?  Just a guess of what's going on:  thread 1 assigns a value for `uniqueID` and logs the request.  Before thread 1 logs the response thread 2 assigns a new value to `uniqueID` (and logs its request).  Then thread 1 logs its response using `uniqueID` which was assigned a new value from thread 2.  Also, `map` and `totalTime` might have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and No i haven't added any thread safe here, I am using spring

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using **Context Map Lookup**, here's a brief example:

Java code sinppet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String uuid = "1";
  logRequestObject("http request", uuid);
  logResponseObject("http response");

  uuid = "2";
  logRequestObject("http request", uuid);
  logResponseObject("http response");
}

static void logRequestObject(Object httpRequest, String uniqueID) {
  ThreadContext.put("uniqueID", uniqueID); // Update uniqueID before logging request and response
  logger.info("This is {}", httpRequest);
}

static void logResponseObject(Object httpResponse) {
  logger.info("This is {}", httpResponse);
}
```

log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern='%level -> %msg %X{uniqueID}%n'/> <!-- Get uniqueID from ThreadContext -->
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Output

```
INFO -> This is http request 1
INFO -> This is http response 1
INFO -> This is http request 2
INFO -> This is http response 2
```

I hope it helps :)