# Micronaut Log4j2 Custom HTTP Header logging

Tags: java, rx-java2, log4j2, micronaut

I want to inject my custom "X-RequestId" (the header will always be provided) header into each and every log message. I'm using Micronaut 3.1.0 and log4j2. I want this to be thread safe, meaning - this must work with multiple threads and across multiple micro-services

Here is my config:

log4j2.xml (resource)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info" name="Demo" packages="request.scope.issue">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    %date{MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

LogFactoryConfig

```
@Filter(Filter.MATCH_ALL_PATTERN)
public class LogFactoryConfig implements LogEventFactory, HttpServerFilter {

    @Inject
    RequestScopedBean requestScopedBean;

    @Override
    public LogEvent createEvent(String loggerName, Marker marker, String fqcn, Level level, Message data, List<Property> properties, Throwable t) {
        //i get a nullpointer since i cannot inject the RequestScopedBean
        Message enrichedMessage = new MementoMessage(requestScopedBean.getxHeader() + " " + data.getFormattedMessage(), data.getFormat(), data.getParameters());
        return new Log4jLogEvent(loggerName, marker, fqcn, level, enrichedMessage, properties, t);
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<MutableHttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, ServerFilterChain chain) {
        //the x-header will always be provided
        requestScopedBean.setxHeader(request.getHeaders().get("X-RequestId"));
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }

    @Override
    public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(HttpRequest<?> request, FilterChain chain) {
        //the x-header will always be provided
        requestScopedBean.setxHeader(request.getHeaders().get("X-RequestId"));
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

RequestScopedBean

```
@RequestScope
public class RequestScopedBean {

    private String xHeader;

    public RequestScopedBean() {
    }

    public RequestScopedBean(String xHeader) {
        this.xHeader = xHeader;
    }

    public String getxHeader() {
        return xHeader;
    }

    public void setxHeader(String xHeader) {
        this.xHeader = xHeader;
    }
}
```

log4j2.component.properties (resource) - this is needed for the LogFactoryConfig to get recognized

```
Log4jLogEventFactory = request.scope.issue.LogFactoryConfig
```

I'm kinda stuck and unable to go further with this. I also tried the ThreadContext.put() method but this won't work if multiple threads are used to finish the request. The goal is to get a log message like this for each and every request and the following log messages:

No additional request id header:

```
11-22 16:11:50,685 INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 623ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
```

If a request kicks in (**REQUEST_ID** - the id which is provided for each request should be logged out) -> see the log factory config:

```
11-22 16:11:50,685 INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - **REQUEST_ID** Startup completed in 623ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097696/how-to-generate-unique-request-id-for-each-log4j-request.

Comment: https://community.appway.com/screen/kb/article/add-the-user-id-to-every-line-in-a-log4j-log-file-1482810864634 may also be helpful.

Comment: Both links are offtopic. It's not about appway and it's about reading a HTTP header to prepend to log statements.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yeah, that did not help at all..
thanks anyway

Comment: "Both links are offtopic. It's not about appway and it's about reading a HTTP header to prepend to log statements."- 1,000 apologies.  I thought MDC would help.  I am sorry for the noise.